# Value of current time (ie. Now()) to be used with JulianDateToDateTime()?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, vcl

I'm trying to convert the value returned by **Now()** to double and then use it in a different function, ie.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    MyFunction_1(Now);
end;

procedure MyFunction_1(TheTime : Double);
begin
    MyFunction_2(TheTime);
end;

procedure MyFunction_1(ModificationDate : Double);
begin
    if JulianDateToDateTime(ModificationDate) < 12345 then
       ...
end;
```

But the problem is, the current time value isn't passed correctly. A simple test for `JulianDateToDateTime(Now);` returned something like this:

```
0/0/0000 16:10:16
```

I'm pretty sure it's something really basic, I just can't figure out what's it is

Any help please?!!

Comment: With `JulianDateToDateTime` you are supposed to supply a Julian date and convert it to a `DateTime` value. I think you want to use `DateTimeToJulianDate` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing it backward. :-)

`JulianDateToDateTime` takes a Julian date as a parameter and returns a TDateTime. It does't take a TDateTime as an argument; that's why you're getting the wrong result. I think you mean to go the other way (`DateTimeToJulianDate`).

From the Delphi documenation:

> Call JulianDateToDateTime to convert a Julian date to the corresponding TDateTime value
>
> Call DateTimeToJulianDate to convert a TDateTime value into the corresponding Julian date.

Here's a quick sample showing the difference:

```
uses DateUtils;

procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  TodaysDate: TDateTime;
  JDate: TDateTime;
begin
  TodaysDate := Date;
  JDate := DateTimeToJulianDate(TodaysDate);
  ShowMessage('Today: ' + FloatToStr(TodaysDate) + #13 +
              'JDate: ' + FloatToStr(JDate) );
end;
```

Here's the output:

[image: JulianDateToDateTime example]

Note that adding one more variable of `TDateTime` type and trying to use `JulianDateToDateTime` raises a range exception:

```
BadDate: TDateTime;
...

BadDate := JulianDateToDateTime(TodaysDate);   // raises exception
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Now()`](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Now) returns a `TDateTime` timestamp which is a `Double`, defined in the unit `System`:

```
TDateTime = type Double;
```

If you want to convert it to a Julian date, you'll need to input it into [`DateTimeToJulianDate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.DateTimeToJulianDate):

```
DateTimeToJulianDate(Now)
```